# "Android Common XML editor" not opening

Tags: android, xml, layout

When I try to open a layout file with "Android Common XML editor" it opens in a text editor. Even when I do it through "Open With", it opens as text. When I create a new project it opens in the correct editor.

Anyone know how I could open it in the "Android Common XML editor"?

Comment: Are you sure that your xml files does not contain errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, Go to `Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Associations` -> set Android common XML editor as default for opening XML file, or otherwise check whether file is stored as `.txt` file and if it is so, change it to `.xml` format.